# keep rows with a set number of unique values and delete the rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
link_id user_id 
    33  420 
    127 156 
    56. 420
```

If I check the number of unique user_id values, I see 1094 values. I want to modify the dataset such that I keep rows which have the first 500 unique values and I want to discard the rest.

```
df.user_id.unique().shape[0]
```

So, in this case, user_id 420 is the first unique value and row 1 and row3 both should be kept. But only rows with the first 500 unique user_ids should be kept. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `factorize`, which enumerates the **unique values** in order found in the series:

```
df[df['user_id'].factorize()[0] < 500]
```

Comment: Can you explain this? Is this keeping all values under 500? Or 500 unique values (can be above 500 too)

Comment: @x89 see explanation if it helps. Basically `factorize` works on unique values, so all rows with the same values are assigned with the same number. You get to keep first 500 **unique ids** with that code.

Comment: is there any way to do this without messing the indices?

Comment: @x89 What do you mean `messing the indices`?

Comment: The index values get all jumbled up after using this. They're no longer in the same order as they were earlier

Comment: They should be in the **same order**. They might not be continuous since you are dropping some intermediate values, but that's what you want do you? I'm sorry if I don't get your question correctly.

Comment: Such an elegant and clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
df[df['user_id'].isin(df['user_id'].unique()[:500])]
```